# How can I remove the underscores from all database data input?

Tags: mysql

I have this query run on a table of mine:

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `checkout` (
  `customer` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `time` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `productid` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(10,0) NOT NULL,
  `tickets` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `index` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`index`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

If, for example, a customer's name is "John Goodwill", in MySQL his name will auto convert to "John_Goodwill". I use the following code to revert:

```
update checkout set customer = replace(customer, '_', ' ');
```

This works for my current customers input in the database, but if any new input is added it goes back to underscore.

What query can I run to cause this to be set for every input?

Comment: MySQL will _not_ convert spaces in strings/varchars with underscores. A space (ASCII 0x20) is a character like any other printable character. You must be doing the conversion somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by adding the following PHP:

> $customer = str_replace("-", " ", $customer); $customer = str_replace("_", " ", $customer);

Answer (score 4):

Clean your data before it reaches the level where your database needs to manipulate it.